# Looking for a photo gallery plugin

Tags: plugins, gallery

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. I have looked all over and can't seem to find what I need.

I am looking for a WP plugin that will allow my site users to easily create their own photo galleries, without having to put the photos into a specific blog post first. In other words, they should be able to just create and publish their own photo galleries as desired.

I'd like something very user-friendly, that I can customize with specific instructions, etc.

I've looked at NextGen and have tested that with some users, but they didn't find it to be very intuitive. (Maybe that's on them, but nevertheless...)

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1):

[Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/) can be [integrated](http://atastypixel.com/blog/wordpress/plugins/galleria-for-wordpress/) with *WordPress* and used with the standard gallery feature set.

Comment: And here the _WordPress_ plugin version, it be well good: [photo galleria](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/photo-galleria)

Answer (score 0):

I have looking for a similar plugin like the one you're looking for. Maybe this list will help.

http://chasesagum.com/8-cool-wordpress-photo-gallery-plugins

And also this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yet-another-photoblog/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for some specific plugin.i think this [Robo gallery](http://www.robogalleryplugin.com/) match your all aspects of requirements.this plugin is user friendly & free of cost.:)